# What day / time does the Decoration Event end?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Right now, it says 2 days remaining - does it reset at midnight in my current timezone according to the iOS time? i.e. Does it end on Mon. Jan 6 at 12:00:00 AM EST?

Still have 12 more levels to decorate and I don't think I'm going to be able to get enough droids to hit that in time. I have the Imp. Bux to summon enough of them, but I'm really close to the final elevator so I'm a bit torn.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the event mentioned in the question is now over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently we were incorrect. They count the days inclusively (the counter says 0 days left). So, it will end tonight at Midnight, 1/7/14 at 00:00.

Comment: Yep, not very intuitive - wished they just printed the specific end-date. I spent almost 40 bux to get Panna City Medicines, but the rate of find the spy has been so ridiculously high that I made it all back within a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it runs on the basis of your own personal timezone.  I base this on the fact that your bitizens' birthdays are determined by that clock, so why would they not use that as the standard for this, too.  My countdown changed over to two days at or some time after midnight here (EST), as well.  So, yes Monday at 00:00 hours (*24 hour time used for clarity*) seems logical.

That said, if you play the game *constantly* between now and then, you will likely get enough decorator droids.  I was able to complete the entire 35 in about two days before the wipe-out bug started rearing it's ugly head.  (I had a REALLY boring day at work!)  And, I did it again, so I now have two Panna City Medicine levels.

With regard to spending Bux, I'd say overall it's not worth it.  Panna City Medicines is not a particularly well stocked level, and therefore will not earn you a particularly large reward compared to the faster elevator.

That said, the final elevator is also a bit of a let down.  When TDS first came out, it was rated for 42 PPM, which was a massive upgrade compared to the previous elevator.  It more than justified the huge jump in price (499 BUX!).  Then, as of version 1.2.1 they changed it to a mere 20 PPM, *but they did not lower the price*.

So, I would weigh out which of the two is more important to you.  **The ONLY reason why spending Bux to unlock the Holiday Special features makes sense is that they are a limited time offering, and you can buy the elevator at any time in the future.**   And, if you feel the need to unlock everything possible in the game, you will want these, too.

Comment: So you're right on the money about the day - it's just past 00:00 here and it rolled down to 1 day remaining. I had the same thoughts about the decision to spend the bux as you have, but I didn't know that they totally nerfed the final elevator - 20 PPM is a total rip off. Now when I think about it, the only reason to get that elevator is to increase my earnings, but I've maxed out all non-imperial floors (I only build the imperial ones as missions require them), so the extra income is actually not that important unless they have new levels coming soon.

Comment: Yeah, the game is rapidly running out of attraction for me now that I've built everything.  I'm just in it to unlock everything now.